# Do exported functions have hint?

Tags: portable-executable

Dependency walker (depends.exe) shows a 'Hint' column for exported functions. As far as I understand the Portable Executable format, exported functions do not have hint. Can someone tell me whether or not exported functions have hint? Actually, only imported functions should have hint..

I finally found the answer to my question...:

In dependency Walker (as well as in Dumpbin), the "Hint" is the position of the Exported Function in the EAT (Export Address Table)! This position has been named "Hint" since the the Loader will use this position when searching for the Functions from the IAT (Import Address Table). As, simple as that!

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx).  I suspect Dependency Walker is calculating the hint for the export 'to be nice'.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the PE/COFF specification. I love this specification. This is what I thought. Dependency walker makes it nice...but since Hint do not exit for exported functions, it shows incorrect data.